# Recursive function returning wrong value in C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I am trying to figure some problem set using recursion but every time my return value is **1**.

Here is my function

```
static int numberOfCoins(int n, int counter)
{
    if (n >= 25)
    {
        counter++;
        numberOfCoins(n - 25,counter);
    }
    else if (n >= 10)
    {
        counter++;
        numberOfCoins(n - 10,counter);
    }
    else if (n >= 5)
    {
        counter++;
        numberOfCoins(n - 5, counter);
    }
    else if (n > 0)
    {
        counter++;
        numberOfCoins(n - 1, counter);
    }

    return counter;
}
```

And here is my call

```
int returnValue = numberOfCoins(32, 0);
Console.WriteLine("counter: " + returnValue);
```

The goal is to return change to user giving him smallest  possible number of coins, available coins are 25, 10, 5 and 1, so in this case `return value` should be **4**. 
I've used breakpoints and all works fine until last minute where counter turns value from **4** to **1.**

Let me say again, i can easily solve this problem using loop, but my goal is to understand `recursion` better.
Any suggestion is helpful, thank you for your time.

Comment: Hint: none of your recursive calls do anything useful, given that you're not using the return value from them. You're doing a bunch of work, but then ignoring the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `numberOfCoins` you just discard the return value. Instead, you should use it and add it to the current count. This will also allow you to remove the `counter` parameter:

```
static int numberOfCoins(int n)
{
    if (n >= 25)
    {
        return 1 + numberOfCoins(n - 25);
    }
    else if (n >= 10)
    {
        return 1 +  numberOfCoins(n - 10);
    }
    else if (n >= 5)
    {
        return 1 +  numberOfCoins(n - 5);
    }
    else if (n > 0)
    {
        return 1 + numberOfCoins(n - 1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you, it's like i was blind to the fact that my function returns value every time i call it